# Как итерировать модуль Python?

Tags: python, атрибуты

Подскажите, как вызвать атрибуты модуля используя цикл?
Я могу вызвать вручную print(string.digits), но если атрибутов много?
Попробовал код ниже, он выдаёт ошибку **AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'part'**

```
import string 


parts = ["ascii_letters", "digits", "punctuation"]

for part in parts:
    
    print(string.part)
```

Comment: `getattr(string, part)`

Comment: Спасибо!
Вопрос закрыт.